# Numpy.isin not detecting presence of a datetime in a vector of datetime64[ns] elements, while equality works

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-datetime

I have an array of `datetime` objects `d1`. I would like to check if each of its elements are present in a series (a `numpy` array, a `pandas` Series, or whatever) of `datetime` objects `d2`.

One element of `d1` is equal to one element of `d2`, and this element is `in` `d2`, but `numpy.isin` is not working here. What am I missing?

If any manipulation should be done, I'd prefer it to be done on `d2` (`d1` should be ideally unchanged).

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
import pandas as pd

d1 = np.array([datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0),
               datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 12, 0)])
d2 = pd.to_datetime(['2021-01-01 12:00:00', '2021-01-02 12:00:00'])
print(d1)
# [datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0) datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 12, 0)]
print(d2)
# DatetimeIndex(['2021-01-01 12:00:00', '2021-01-02 12:00:00'], 
#               dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)


print(d1[1] == d2[0])
# True
print(d1[1] in d2)
# True
print(np.isin(d1, d2))
# [False False] # !!! What is happening here?
# Expected result:
# [False True]
```

Comment: `d1` has `dtype=object` instead of `dtype=dtype('<M8[ns]')` you should really use the latter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me working pandas solution for compare both `DatetimeIndex` by [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
print(pd.DatetimeIndex(d1).isin(d2))
[False  True]
```

Like @juanpa.arrivillaga mentioned, for working `np.isin` need same types here, so convert `d1` to datetimes and then compare

```
print(d1.astype('datetime64[us]'))
#another way of converting
print(d1.astype('<M8[ns]'
['2021-01-01T00:00:00.000000' '2021-01-01T12:00:00.000000']
```

---

```
print (np.isin(d1.astype('datetime64[us]'), d2))
[False  True]

print (np.isin(d1.astype('<M8[ns]'), d2))
[False  True]
```